# launchd redirect stderr/out to timestamped log files?

Tags: xml, macos, launchd

I have a properties list to schedule a job with `launchd` to run every day.  I can easily create a log file that redirects the std err/out to the location of my choosing as such

```
 <key>StandardOutPath</key>
 <string>/var/log/myjob.out</string>
 <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
 <string>/var/log/myjob.err</string>
 <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>15</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>54</integer>
    </dict>
```

However this will keep appending to the same log file every day

What I want is for it to redirect to a unique log file every time it runs with a timestamp in the name

for example

```
 <key>StandardOutPath</key>
 <string>/var/log/myjob_%Y_%M_%d.out</string>
 <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
 <string>/var/log/myjob_%Y_%M_%d.err</string>
 <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>15</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>54</integer>
    </dict>
```

would output `myjob_%Y_%M_%d.out` and `myjob_%Y_%M_%d.err` with a unique timestamp for each day it runs.

I have looked at creating environment variables and passing that to XML but I can't figure out a way to get the timestamp into the XML. Trying variable interpolation as in bash did not work as it interpreted the following with `$(date +%s)` asa literal string

```
 <key>StandardOutPath</key>
 <string>/var/log/myjob_$(date +%s).out</string>
 <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
 <string>/var/log/myjob_$(date +%s).err</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a (clean) way to do this directly in the .plist file. If your job itself is a shell script, I'd add a bit to the beginning of the script to redirect the outputs:

```
exec >"/var/log/myjob_$(date +%s).out" 2>"/var/log/myjob_$(date +%s).err"
```

If it's not a script (or not modifiable), I'd write a wrapper script to do the redirects, then `exec` the real program. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Wrapper script to redirect stdout and stderr to
# timestamped log files

exec /path/to/executable "$@" >"/var/log/myjob_$(date +%s).out" 2>"/var/log/myjob_$(date +%s).err"
```

Note that using `exec` to run the actual program means the shell running the wrapper gets replaced by the actual program, rather than hanging out as a useless parent process waiting for it to exit. The `"@"` passes on any arguments passed to the wrapper; if the actual script doesn't take arguments, you can omit it.